# Windows Azure - leader instance without single point of failure

Tags: azure, singleton, azure-worker-roles

I am looking for a way to have a "Singleton" module over multiple worker role instances.
I would like to have a parallel execution model with Queues and multiple worker roles in Azure.

The idea is that would like to have a "master" instance, that is let's say checking for new data, and is scheduling it by adding it to a queue, processing all messages from a special queue, that is not processed by nobody else, and has mounted blob storage as a virtual drive, with read/write access.

I will always have **only one** "master instance". When that master instance goes down for some reason, another instance from the one already instantiated should very quickly be "elected" for a master instance (couple of seconds). This should happen before the broken instance is replaced by a new one by the Azure environment (about 15 min).

So it will be some kind of self-organizing, dynamic environment.
I was thinking of having some locking, based on a storage or table data. the opportunity to set lock timeouts and some kind of "watchdog" timer if we can talk with microprocessor terminology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is general approach to what you seek to achieve.

First, your master instance. You could do your check based on instance ID. It is fairly easy. You need [RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.currentroleinstance.aspx) to get the "Current instance", now compare the [Id property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleinstance.id.aspx) with what you get out of [RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Role.Instances](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.role.instances.aspx) first member ordered by Id. Something like:

```
var instance = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance;
if(instance.Id.Equals(instance.Role.Instances.OrderBy(ins => ins.Id).First().Id))
{
 // you are in the single master
}
```

Now you need to elect master upon "Healing"/recycling.
You need to get the RoleEnvironment's [Changed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.changed.aspx) event. Check if it is [TopologyChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironmenttopologychange.aspx) (just check whether it is topology change, you don't need the exact change in topology). And if it is Topology Change - elect the next master based on the above algorithm. Check out [this great blog post](http://brentdacodemonkey.wordpress.com/2011/09/24/leveraging-the-roleentrypoint-year-of-azure-week-12/) on how to exactly perform events hooking and change detection.

Forgot to add.

If you like locks - blob lease is the best way to acquire / check locks. However working with just the RoleEnvironment events and the simple master election based on Instance ID, I don't think you'll need that complicated locking mechanism. Besides - everything lives in the Queue until it is **successfully** processed. So if the master dies before it processes something, the "next master" will process it.

Comment: Why is there a need to check Topology changes? i am thinking of using your sample code in my worker thread (run procedure) just right after Thread.Sleep. 
So even if there is a change in topology there will always be a first (by id) worker instance that will behave as the leader.
Am i missing something?

Comment: I'd assert that the blob locking mechanism isn't really complicated. I've posted some sample code on my blog: http://brentdacodemonkey.wordpress.com/2012/07/27/the-traffic-cop-pattern/

Comment: The role instance based solution takes a dependency on the hosting platform (cloud service in this case) which isn't ideal. This would reduce the ability to re-host the service on other platforms.
The blob lease lock solution is better IMHO.

Comment: Well the question is about cloud services worker roles, which already is a hard plattform dependency.... So the possible solutions are enlisted... Also please pay attention to the dates of questions and answers When commenting. ..