# Windows Azure - Leader Election with Blog Lease Race Condition

Tags: azure, singleton, azure-blob-storage

I was looking at Leader Election Pattern from Cloud Design Pattern (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn568104.aspx). It uses an approach that was described in other places as well (http://blog.smarx.com/posts/managing-concurrency-in-windows-azure-with-leases) and mentioned in at least one other question on Stack Overflow ([Windows Azure - leader instance without single point of failiure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259120/windows-azure-leader-instance-without-single-point-of-failiure)).

In general the election process boils down to processes competing for Blob Storage lease. Lease itself is exclusive so only one process can hold it at a given point in time. In the Leader Election Pattern the lease is initially acquired for a predefined period of time (between 15 and 60 sec) and renewed by a background thread running on the process holding a lease.

What I was wandering is whether this solution does not suffer from a possible race condition. Is it not possible that if for some reason a current leader does not manage to renew lock in time (extensive load, network delays) a different process in the distributed system may assume that it is a leader as well?

As far as I could understand the approach is used in EventProcessorHost for Event Hubs partition leases.

Edit:

I think this http://redis.io/topics/distlock explains how to be sure there are no two procesess that both think they are leaders in case of partitioning. In short the algorithm assumes that proces will stop immediatelly after figuring out that it cannot renew lock. If it tries to renew lock long enough before lease expires there will be no other proces that can grab the lock.

Comment: Read the links you shared, they list exactly those problems. You have to take additional measures. http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=distributed+leader+election

Comment: Also: This question doesn't really work very well on its own, as it requires *everyone* to traverse the links and read additional info to even figure out what, exactly, you're asking about.

Comment: Could you give me a concrete part of the links that I shared which mention this problem? I might have missed something but I cannot find it being mentioned. What are sample additional measures that you are referring to?

Comment: David: good point. Just added a general overview of the pattern mentioned